# If $n$ is divisible by a perfect square then $n$ is not a Carmichael number.

Tags: analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, pseudoprimes

If $n$ is divisible by a perfect square then $n$ is not a Carmichael number.

Going through the proof from Neal Koblitz's A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography...I am facing some difficulties to understand the proof....seeking help for that..

[image: Attaching the proof from the book for ready ref..]

Thank you..

Comment: What don't you understand? That's a lot of proof to try to explain without knowing what is confusing you. Help people help you.

Comment: firstly how g is a generator modulo p^2 imply that $g^{p(p-1)}$ is the lowest power of g which is

Comment: That is the definition of "generator" in this context, i.e. a residue mod $p^2$ which is relatively prime to $p^2$ (i.e. not a multiple of $p$), whose successive powers attain all the residues mod $p^2$ that are relatively prime to $p^2$ (aka, the multiplicative subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^\times$).

Comment: Some of the "complexity" of this proof is due to the need, from the definition of Carmichael number, to exhibit a base $b$ for which the pseudoprime test of $n$ fails.  We need to have $b$ coprime to $n$ for this purpose (since the definition of $n$ being a Carmichael number only requires the pseudoprime test to succeed for bases that are coprime to $n$).